# Storing output of a recursive formula

Tags: excel, vba

In the folder Data I have three other folders that each contain .xlsm files.
To try and go through all these folders I'm trying a recursive formula like this or in a collection to find all the files.
I need to store the full path of these files to use in the main macro at the bottom and do various things.
Currently this stores the last file in the iteration but I need a full list, I've tried using an array but i'm struggling to either store it or send it out of the function.
Any help would be appreciated

```
Function LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folderPath As String)

Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFilePath As String
Dim numFolders As Long
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim variable As String
If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

While Len(fileName) <> 0

    If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then
 
        fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName
 
        If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
            folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
            numFolders = numFolders + 1
        Else
            variable = folderPath & fileName
            'Debug.Print variable
            'Debug.Print folderPath & fileName
        End If
 
    End If
 
    fileName = Dir()

Wend

For i = 0 To numFolders - 1

   LoopAllSubFolders folders(i)
 
Next i
LoopAllSubFolders = variable
End Function


Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()
Output = LoopAllSubFolders("Data\")
Debug.Print Output

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use a collection for example to add the results, eg.:

```
Option Explicit
Dim output
Dim col As Collection
Function LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folderPath As String)
Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFilePath As String
Dim numFolders As Long
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim variable As String
If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

While Len(fileName) <> 0

    If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then
 
        fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName
 
        If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
            folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
            numFolders = numFolders + 1
        Else
            variable = folderPath & fileName
          Call col.Add(variable, variable)
            ' Debug.Print variable
            'Debug.Print folderPath & fileName
        End If
 
    End If
 
    fileName = Dir()

Wend

For i = 0 To numFolders - 1

   LoopAllSubFolders folders(i)
 
Next i
LoopAllSubFolders = variable
End Function


Sub loopAllSubFolderSelectStartDirectory()
Dim i As Long
Set col = New Collection
output = LoopAllSubFolders("Data\")
For i = 1 To col.Count
Debug.Print col(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really good thanks, I think the recursive formula was making it more confusing for me and couldn't think how to do it. I can't mark it up but this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

### Return *File Paths* in Collection Using FileSystemObject Object

**Utilization (Example)**

```vb
Sub CollSubfolderFilePathsTEST()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const FilePattern As String = "*.xlsm"
    Const IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = False
    
    ' Return the file paths in a collection ('collFilePaths')
    Dim collFilePaths As Collection: Set collFilePaths _
        = CollSubfolderFilePaths(FolderPath, FilePattern, IncludeFolderPath)
    
    ' Validate the collection.
    If collFilePaths Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    ' Loop through the collection to print each item.
    For Each Item In collFilePaths
        Debug.Print Item
    Next Item

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the paths of all files of a folder ('FolderPath')
'               and all of its subfolders in a collection.
' Remarks:      It uses the FileSystemObject object.
'               If an error occurs, if the initial folder doesn't exist, or
'               if no file is found, the function will return 'Nothing'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CollSubfolderFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "*.*", _
    Optional ByVal IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = True) _
As Collection
    Const ProcName As String = "CollSubfolderFilePaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Create and reference a FileSystemObject object ('fso').
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the initial folder path ('FolderPath').
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then Exit Function
    
    ' Define the Paths collection ('collPaths') to hold the paths of all files
    ' in the initial folder path and in each of its subfolders.
    Dim collPaths As Collection: Set collPaths = New Collection
    
    ' Define the Queue collection ('collQueue') to hold
    ' the initial folder (object) and all of its subfolders (objects)
    ' before the paths of their files are stored in the Paths collection
    ' and they are removed (from the Queue collection).
    Dim collQueue As Collection: Set collQueue = New Collection
    ' Add the initial folder (object) to the Queue collection.
    collQueue.Add fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object ' Current Folder
    Dim fsoSubfolder As Object ' Current Subfolder
    Dim fsoFile As Object ' Current File in the Current Folder

    Do Until collQueue.Count = 0
        
        ' Reference the current folder ('fsoFolder'),
        ' the first folder in the Queue collection.
        Set fsoFolder = collQueue(1)
        ' Remove the current (first) folder from the Queue collection.
        collQueue.Remove 1 ' dequeue!
         
         ' Loop through the subfolders ('fsoSubfolder') of the current folder.
        For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders
            ' Add the current subfolder to the Queue collection.
            collQueue.Add fsoSubfolder ' enqueue!
        Next fsoSubfolder
        
        If IncludeFolderPath Then ' do not skip the intial folder path
            ' Loop through the files ('fsoFile') in the folder.
            For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
                ' Using the Like operator, check the current file's name
                ' against the file pattern ensuring case-insensitivity
                ' by using the LCase function.
                If LCase(fsoFile.Name) Like LCase(FilePattern) Then
                    ' Add the current file's path to the collection.
                    collPaths.Add fsoFile.Path
                End If
            Next fsoFile
        Else ' skip the initial folder path
            IncludeFolderPath = True
        End If
    
    Loop
    
    ' When no file was found, avoid passing a collection with 0 items
    ' to be able to always validate it by checking it just against 'Nothing'
    ' in the calling procedure.
    If collPaths.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    ' Pass the Paths collection to the result of the function.
    Set CollSubfolderFilePaths = collPaths

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

### Return *Folder Paths* in Collection Using FileSystemObject Object

**Utilization (Example)**

```vb
Sub CollSubfolderPathsTEST()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = True
    
    ' Return the folder paths in a collection ('collFolderPaths')
    Dim collFolderPaths As Collection: Set collFolderPaths _
        = CollSubfolderPaths(FolderPath, IncludeFolderPath)
    
    ' Validate the collection.
    If collFolderPaths Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    ' Loop through the collection to print each item.
    For Each Item In collFolderPaths
        Debug.Print Item
    Next Item

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the paths of a folder ('FolderPath')
'               and all of its subfolders in a collection.
' Remarks:      It uses the FileSystemObject object.
'               If an error occurs, if the initial folder doesn't exist, or
'               if no folder is found (only when 'IncludFolderPath = False'),
'               the function will return 'Nothing'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CollSubfolderPaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = True) _
As Collection
    Const ProcName As String = "CollSubFolderPaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Create and reference a FileSystemObject object ('fso').
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the initial folder path ('FolderPath').
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then Exit Function
    
    ' Define the Paths collection ('collPaths') to hold
    ' the initial folder path and the paths of each subfolder.
    Dim collPaths As Collection: Set collPaths = New Collection
    
    ' Define the Queue collection ('collQueue') to hold
    ' the initial folder (object) and all of its subfolders (objects)
    ' before their path is stored in the Paths collection
    ' and they are removed (from the Queue collection).
    Dim collQueue As Collection: Set collQueue = New Collection
    ' Add the initial folder (object) to the Queue collection.
    collQueue.Add fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object ' Current Folder
    Dim fsoSubfolder As Object ' Current Subfolder

    Do Until collQueue.Count = 0
        
        ' Reference the current folder ('fsoFolder'),
        ' the first folder in the Queue collection.
        Set fsoFolder = collQueue(1)
        ' Remove the current (first) folder from the Queue collection.
        collQueue.Remove 1 ' dequeue!
        ' Add the path of the current folder to the Paths collection.
        collPaths.Add fsoFolder.Path
        
        ' Loop through the subfolders of the current folder (referencing each).
        For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders
            ' Add the current subfolder to the Queue collection.
            collQueue.Add fsoSubfolder ' enqueue!
        Next fsoSubfolder
    
    Loop
    
    ' The following illustration helped me to understand the code
    ' in the Do...Until loop whose part related to the Queue collection
    ' is emulating the functionality of a FIFO type (first in, first out)
    ' data structure called a queue.
    
    ' Level    Folder Structure
    '   1      A
    '   2      B     C   D
    '   3      E F       G H I
    '   4                J
    
    ' Iteration  Removed  Path     Added  Added Description  Count  Status
    '     1         A     A        B,C,D  Subfolders of A      3    B,C,D
    '     2         B     A\B      E,F    Subfolders of B      4    C,D,E,F
    '     3         C     A\C                                  3    D,E,F
    '     4         D     A\D      G,H,I  Subfolders of D      5    E,F,G,H,I
    '     5         E     A\B\E                                4    F,G,H,I
    '     6         F     A\B\F                                3    G,H,I
    '     7         G     A\D\G    J      Subfolders of G      3    H,I,J
    '     8         H     A\D\H                                2    I,J
    '     9         I     A\D\I                                1    J
    '    10         J     A\D\G\J                              0
      
    If Not IncludeFolderPath Then
        ' When the path of the initial folder was the only path
        ' in the Paths collection, avoid passing a collection with 0 items
        ' to be able to always validate it by checking it just against 'Nothing'
        ' in the calling procedure.
        If collPaths.Count = 1 Then Exit Function
        ' Remove the path of the initial folder from the Paths collection.
        collPaths.Remove 1
    End If
    
    ' Pass the Paths collection to the result of the function.
    Set CollSubfolderPaths = collPaths

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```